# How to save a code in ThisOutlookSession as a script which I can choose, when I choose the "run a script" rule in Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I ran a code in VBA in Outlook to save a .csv attachment of a particular sender with a particular subject line to a folder on my local drive. This code was run on ThisOutlookSession and not as a module. I tried to use the "run a script" rule in my outlook, but when the pop-up window appears with the option to choose a script, it is blank. Can someone help me out with this? How do I save the code in ThisOutlookSession for it appear as an option in the scripts pop-up window of "run a script" rule in Outlook?

[image: Pop-up window to select script after selecting rule]

Answer (score 0):

A VBA method should have the following signature:

```
Public Sub Test(item as MailItem)
   ' do whatever you need here
End Sub
```

You can read more about that in the [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) article.